# if else on variable link input

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have a method of pulling Youtube video data from API links. I use Wordpress and ran into a snag.

In order to pull the thumbnail, views, uploader and video title I need the user to input the 11 character code at the end of watch?v=**_______**. This is documented with specific instructions for the user, but what if they ignore it and paste the whole url?

```
// the url 'code' the user should input.
_gXp4hdd2pk

// the wrong way, when the user pastes the whole url.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gXp4hdd2pk
```

If the user accidentally pastes the entire URL and not the 11 character code then is there a way I can use PHP to grab either the code or whats at the end of this url (11 characters after 'watch?v='?

Here is my PHP code to pull the data:

```
// $url is the code at the end of 'watch?v=' that the user inputs
$url = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'youtube_url', $single = true);

// $code is a variable for placing the $url in a youtube link so I can output it to an API link
$code = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $url;

// $code is called at the end of this oembed code, allowing me to decode json data and pull elements from json to echo in my html
// echoed output returns json file. example: http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gXp4hdd2pk
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url='.urlencode($code));
```

Im looking for something like...

"if user inputs code, use this block of code, else if user inputs whole url use a different block of code, else throw error."

Or... if they use the whole URL can PHP only use a specific section of that url...?

EDIT: Thank you for all the answers! I am new to PHP, so thank you all for your patience. It is difficult for graphic designers to learn PHP, even reading the PHP manual can give us headaches. All of your answers were great and the ones ive tested have worked. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I am not good with PHP. Im shocked I was able to come up with the code I have in my post. Can you explain how you would use `explode('_', $url)` with my code? I am looking it up as we speak. If itll parse my data input then that can be a solution.

Comment: @Darren : In this case, each data must be starts with underscore(`_`). But it should be dynamic.

Comment: @Ranjith, correct, the underscore is actually part of the code for that specific video example.

Comment: then `explode('?v=', $url)`. (Provided there aren't any other parameters in the url)

Comment: @Darren : He given an sample data only. In all the time it's not be same

Comment: @Darren there is a chance for more URL parameters to occur. If a user pastes a video from a playlist the 11 character code will still be inside of it, but parameters append to the url after it. Example: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gXp4hdd2pk&list=RD_gXp4hdd2pk#t=184`, even though all we want is `_gXp4hdd2pk`, after `watch?v=` and before `&list`

Comment: @FlannelBeard : You want to `&list=` data too.

Comment: Wow this is ridiculous, can you not think for yourselves? `$der = explode('?v=', $url);` gives you `Array
(
    [0] => https://www.youtube.com/watch
    [1] => _gXp4hdd2pk&list=RD_gXp4hdd2pk#t=184
)` so you then go `$d = explode('&', $re[1]);` which gives you `Array
(
    [0] => _gXp4hdd2pk
    [1] => list=RD_gXp4hdd2pk#t=184
)` and bang, magically your video id is in **`$d[0]`**.

Comment: Negative, as the code varies after `&list=`, there is an `RD` placed after it. We do not need this. In order to decode the json in the example link I need the 11 character code. I have this working properly [here](http://www.elevancement.com/), but the thought occurs that some users might not read instructions, rush the posting, and paste the full url in the post, which will throw script errors on the page. If the 11 character code is input it will work. Im trying to make the theme full proof :P

Comment: @Darren, no need to get rude. I just started learning more intermediate PHP a few months ago. Im a graphic designer, programming does not come naturally to me. So, no, I cannot think for myself and asked for help after messing with it for the past 3 hours. :)

Comment: @FlannelBeard I apologise, it's been a long day here if you know what I mean. You just need to read the manuals for this kind of information. I'll see what answer I can whip up for you

Comment: @Darren, it is quite all right. You have to understand, a lot of graphic designers try desperately to learn languages like PHP but struggle. We are visual creatives, and code some times hits us like a brick wall. Ive read the `explode` manual but I could not make sense of it to fit with my code. Thats all. :) That is why i asked. I am trying some answers posted below that use Explode, im fixing to upload and test now.

Comment: @FlannelBeard [**see answer.**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24299551/2518525)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple option for you to do, unless you want to use `regex` like [**Nisse Engström's Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24299505/2518525).

Using the function [**`parse_url()`**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.parse-url.php) you could do something like this:

```
    $url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gXp4hdd2pk&list=RD_gXp4hdd2pk#t=184';
    $split = parse_url('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gXp4hdd2pk&list=RD_gXp4hdd2pk#t=184');

    $params = explode('&', $split['query']);
    $video_id = str_replace('v=', '', $params[0]);
```

now `$video_id` would return:

```
_gXp4hdd2pk
```

from the `$url` supplied in the above code.

I suggest you read the `parse_url()` documentation to ensure you understand and grasp it all :-)

---

**Update**
for your comment.

You'd use something like this to make sure the parsed value is a valid URL:

```
// this will check if valid url
if (filter_var($code, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    // its valid as it returned true
    // so run the code
    $url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gXp4hdd2pk&list=RD_gXp4hdd2pk#t=184';
    $split = parse_url('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gXp4hdd2pk&list=RD_gXp4hdd2pk#t=184');

    $params = explode('&', $split['query']);
    $video_id = str_replace('v=', '', $params[0]);
} else {
    // they must have posted the video code as the if check returned false.
    $video_id = $url;
}
```

Comment: Works, and I will check out the `parse_url()`, seems super handy, as is `explode():`. Being new to PHP some of this is a little hard to comprehend without seeing its implementation :)

Comment: @FlannelBeard This is probably a better alternative to the one you accepted. as it will fetch **only** the video id, where as the `explode()` answers posted will also optionally post the rest of the url

Comment: Let me test something really quick on this :)

Comment: Running into a snag. Not sure how to fix. I need to use `$url = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'youtube_url', $single = true);`, which is what the user inputs (full url or code). I need that to echo as a string in `$split = parse_url();`. However if they just use the code we have issues. Should I instruct them to just paste the entire URL and save the trouble? I hope this makes sense.

Perhaps: `$split = parse_url($url);`?

Comment: @FlannelBeard Updating answer now

Comment: Got this working. `$url = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'youtube_url', $single = true);` and then `$split = parse_url($url);`. What I have to do now is change my instructions to paste the entire youtube URL and they will have 0 issues. This has been tested with multiple types of youtube links. Thank you, sincerely you have made my night. I've much to learn in PHP but I am actively trying.

Comment: @FlannelBeard Updated the answer for you, hopefully that covers what you need :-)

Comment: it is exactly what I have been after for about 5 hours now :) was about to go insane figuring it out on my own, haha. Thank you very much.

Comment: @FlannelBeard Perfectly alright. We all have to start somewhere, A little tip I might add is always debug with `var_dump()` & `print_r()` to see what the functions return and work from there. Also it's a great thing to have `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);` set on when developing :)

Comment: understood, and thank you for the tips. So far I have managed to learn `die()`, and found that useful for debugging a function script. Ill read up on `var_dump()` and `print_r()` to see how I can use them ahead of asking questions here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$code = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gXp4hdd2pk';

if (filter_var($code, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) == TRUE) { 

   // if `$code` is valid url

   $code_arr = explode('?v=', $code);
   $query_str = explode('&', $code_arr[1]);

   $new_code =  $query_str[0];
} else {
    // if `$code` is not a valid url like '_gXp4hdd2pk' 
    $new_code = $code;
}

echo $new_code;
```

Comment: This works flawlessly as well and prevents a lot of the accidental mess ups that users might paste in unknowingly. Id like to think that users would read my documentation but I had better prepare for the worst :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just try as follows ..

```
  $url =" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gXp4hdd2pk";
$url= explode('?v=', $url);
$endofurl = end($url);
echo $endofurl;
```

Replace $url variable with input .

Comment: This worked flawlessly for me, there was 10 lines of code I did not show here but it integrated seemlessly. Thank you! Are we able to filter anything that comes after the code? I ran across `&list` and `&index`. I only wish to safeguard my theme as much as possible. :)

Comment: @FlannelBeard : It will returns the `&list=adsfadf` data too. [Demo here](https://ideone.com/TmLSbv). Your wish also same?

Comment: If you fork this using my method then there is a flaw. Using `gdata` urls need to be specific. If the url has `&list` or `&index` parameters after the 11 character code then it cannot be implemented into some `gdata` urls, which are used to pull various data (thumbnails, views, uploader, title, etc). Im sorry to harp on that, but if you are forking this then you might want to try and add a filter to exclude `&index` and `&list`. It might be very helpful for others down the road.

Answer (score 1):

```
$m = array();

if (preg_match ('#^(https?://www.youtube.com/watch\\?v=)?(.+)$#', $url, $m)) {
  $code = $m[2];
} else {
  /* No match */
}
```

The code uses a [Regular Expression](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) to match the user input (the subject) against a pattern. The pattern is enclosed in a pair of delimiters (`#`) of your choice. The rest of the pattern works like this:

- `^` matches the beginning of the string.
- `(...)` creates a subpattern.
- `?` matches 0 or 1 of the preceeding character or subpattern.
- `https?` matches "http" or "https".
- `\?` matches "?".
- `(.+)` matches 1 or more arbitrary charactes. The `.` matches any character (except newline). `+` matches 1 or more of the preceeding character or subpattern.
- `$` matches the end of the string.

In other words, optionally match an `http` or `https` base URL, followed by the video code.

The matches are then written to `$m`. `$m[0]` contains the entire string, `$m[1]` contains the first subpattern (base URL) and `$m[2]` contains the second subpattern (code).

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little of how your code works? Id like to understand it, as it is shorter than the other answers.

Comment: @FlannelBeard: Explanation added.

Comment: The `split()` and `explode()` solution is probably better since the Youtube URL may contain other query parts than the `?v=...`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! I will try to learn it and use it when I can. :)

Answer (score 1):

I instruct my users to copy and paste the whole youtube url.
Then, I do this:

```
$video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gXp4hdd2pk'; // this is from user input
$parsed_url = parse_url($video_url);
parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $query);
$vidID = isset($query['v']) ? $query['v'] : NULL;
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/". $vidID; // this is used for the Api
```

Comment: This seems like it would work too. Have you ran across anything to be able to pull a Channel Banner using gdata?

Comment: This can filter the $v variable to complicated urls, like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4ooyhNsGao&list=RDV4ooyhNsGao#t=0

Comment: sorry, i haven't look into banner yet